# VoIP phone not working for outgoing calls

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, voip

I am trying to set up a VoIP phone hosted by Zadarma.

I am using a Grandstream HT801 ATA that is connected via ethernet to a TP-LINK Deco M4R mesh system.

The ATA is successfully registering the phone and receiving incoming calls. But I cannot make out going calls.

Searching the web I see that in can be a problem with the firewall, or a NAT (or possibly double NAT) problem or something called SIP ALG.

I don't know where to start investigating the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what the problem might be. I am trying to understand if this specific set-up can cause any known problems.

Comment: Have you spoken to your provider?  It could be an issue on their end - especially if you can receive incoming calls.

Comment: They said they don't see my calls reaching their server